# What’s the sum of four vectors that form a loop?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

4 vectors that connectod end to end.
what is the sum of all vectors ?
[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is $\vec 0$ because it comes back to the start point.

Comment: Boo. Shame on you for giving away the answer so fast without making the OP think about it.

Comment: Well, my fingers just move:)

Comment: ok i got it :) thanks

Comment: Dear mathlove : This literally answers the question, but it doesn't really explain anything. (Big difference!) In answering the OP's question, you've simultaneously raised a new question about why coming back to the start point should mean it adds to zero. Consider adding more to support for that to "close the loop" of this explanation! :)

Answer (score 3):

As you hopefully know, the picture of vector addition is this: to add $v+w$, arrange them so that the tip of $v$ touches the tail of $w$, and then draw the vector whose tail starts at the tail of $v$ and whose tip ends at the tip of $w$.

In the first picture below, we have $d+e=c$. In the second picture, swapping the head and tip of $c$ we get $-c$, and we see that $a+b=-c$.

[image: modified diagram]

It follows that $a+b+d+e=c-c=0$.

The main idea is that if you have a triangle with vector edges arranged in a cycle, then the sum of the sides is zero. (Try proving this as we did above!) As you might guess, any broken line made of vectors arranged tip-to-tail which forms a closed loop can be decomposed into such triangles.

Answer (score 1):

How much have the vectors moved horizontally. How much have they moved vertically? Does this tell you anything about their sum? What happens if a vector has these values for its components?